# Directive Does Not Render, No Errors in Console

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

A bit of a head-scratcher: I've defined a directive that will not render when I use it in the markup. There are no errors reported in the browser console.

markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Players Character Sheet</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="character.js"></script>
    <script src="directives/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="directives/character-generator.js"></script>
    <script src="directives/basic-stats.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="character.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="character">
    <h1>Players Character Sheet</h1>
    <character-generator></character-generator>
    <basic-statistics></basic-statistics>
</body>
</html>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('character.directives', [])
.directive('characterGenerator', [function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'directives/character-generator.html',
  replace: true,
  scope: {},
  controller: function() {
      $scope.character = {}
      $scope.character.dirty = false
      $scope.character.uuid = null
      $scope.button = document.getElementById('saveButton')
      $scope.load = function() {}
      $scope.save = function() {}
      $scope.willLoad = function() {
        $scope.button.onclick = $scope.load
      }
      $scope.willSave = function() {
        $scope.button.innerText = 'save'
        $scope.button.onclick = $scope.save
      }
    } // controller
  } // return
}])
```

For comparison, there is a second directive that *is* rendering, right below the other one.

[image]

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle, you have `<body ng-app="runequest-character">`, but you don't define the module `runequest-character`.  The only module you have defined is `runequest-character.directives`. Try `<body ng-app="runequest-character.directives">` instead.

There's at least one additional problem with your fiddle.  The templateUrl defined in your directive, `directives/character-generator.html` but that html file is not included in the fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Fiddle. In my haste to provide a concise example, I ended up making many typos. The post has been revised to be more complete, along with the fiddle link (which now references a base version of the code therein).

Comment: Looking at your updated fiddle.  There's a bunch of errors in the console.  Most of them are due to your <script> tags including files that don't exist.  The one I don't understand is an injector that states it can't instantiate module runequest-character.  I don't understand it because I don't see runequest-character anywhere in your fiddle.  Perhaps an artifact from a previous edit.  I can't take a deep look now, but will take a look again later.

Comment: I'm clearly struggling with Fiddle and failing to communicate my challenge with this directive I'm developing. Please don't expend any more than a few minutes of your time. I don't intend anyone to untangle the mess in Fiddle I've created. I thank you again.

Comment: Well let me know if you get a fiddle working that doesn't have all the script reference errors but still exhibits your problem.  I'd love to have another look

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, as I was attempting to replicate the issue with a more concise example to share here. Although it isn't evident from the example in my original post, see if you can figure out what's wrong with this picture :)

**file1**:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
```

**file2**:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
.directive('directive1', [ function() {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'directives/d1.html',
    replace:true,
    scope:{},
    controller:function() {
    } // controller
} // return
}])
```

**file3**:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
.directive('directive2', [ function() {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:'directives/d2.html',
    replace:true,
    scope:{},
    controller:function() {
    } // controller
} // return
}])
```